# Get Facebook wall data to web portal

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I have web portal. I need to somehow get all Facebook wall posts from just one specific user or group( that represents my web portal). I need to have wall posts available on my web portal for further processing.

I will be also needing an option for posting messages from web portal to FB user/group wall.

I haven`t worked with FB API until now, so any materials, tutorials that can lead me in right direction would be of great help.

Can this be done without creating Facebook application?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,
Facebook just like that does not share its user information.
you will have to create an app on facebook to authorize urself,and on your web portal you will have to sek users permission before getting any user info.

craete facebook app here https://developers.facebook.com/apps

You can choose between javascript sdk and graph api on how you want to get user data.
You can use publish_stream permisiion to get the post on user wall.

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be done without creating Facebook application?

**NO**

Tutorials and materials:

1. [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)
2. [Samples & How-Tos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/)
3. [Google](http://www.google.com/), but I would be careful here. Try to search for updated tutorials (written or updated on 2011)

Answer (score -1):

I used this http://neosmart.de/social-media/facebook-wall its fb.wall plugin into jQuery .js library. It easy and can be edited symply via CSS